# PCF - App not allowed to create tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cloud-foundry, limesurvey, pcf

I have deployed successfully limesurvey.org application (LAMP) to Pivotal Cloud. The application mostly works as expected except MySQL database does not allows the application to create tables. When a given survey is activated the app needs to create tables to store the responses.

I have installed the same application on premises (Linux) and I have no issues. I was advised by another team that has deployed same app (different version) to PCF to use the script (below) to capture the VCAP_SERVICES information to connect the database. However after "cf push" the application does not work at all. It's a PHP script. I have seem a similar code in Java.

Why do I need to provide VCAP_SERVICES info to the database on PCF?

Perhaps if I understand what the script is trying to do I will be able to address the issue.

Any information and or tips will be highly appreciated.

```
class ApplicationConfiguration {
    private static function decrypt_password($base64_encrypted_password, $cf_instance_ip, $uuid) {
        $rsa_private_key = self::lookup_rsa_private_key ( $cf_instance_ip, $uuid );
        $encrypted_password = base64_decode ( $base64_encrypted_password );
        $decryption_result = openssl_private_decrypt ( $encrypted_password, $decrypted_password, $rsa_private_key );

        return $decrypted_password;
    }
    private static function lookup_rsa_private_key($cf_instance_ip, $uuid) {
        $private_key_lookup_url = 'http://' . $cf_instance_ip . ':1199/v1/cred/private_key/' . $uuid;

        // SSL certificate is currently self-signed, disable all validation
        $contextOptions = array (
                'ssl' => array (
                        'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false 
                ) 
        );

        $rsa_private_key = file_get_contents ( $private_key_lookup_url, false, stream_context_create ( $contextOptions ) );

        return $rsa_private_key;
    }
    public static function getApplicationConfigurations() {
        $appConfigurations = array ();

        $dbDetails = getenv ( "VCAP_SERVICES" );

        $appConfigurations ["debug"] = getenv ( "DEBUG" );
        $appConfigurations ["debugsql"] = getenv ( "DEBUG_SQL" );

        if (getenv ( "TABLE_PREFIX" ) == NULL) {
            $appConfigurations ["tablePrefix"] = 'lime_';
        } else {
            $appConfigurations ["tablePrefix"] = getenv ( "TABLE_PREFIX" );
        }

        $dbDetailsObject = json_decode ( $dbDetails, true );

        $credentials = array ();

        if (array_key_exists ( "mariadb", $dbDetailsObject ) && $dbDetailsObject ["mariadb"] != NULL) {
            $credentials = $dbDetailsObject ['mariadb'] [0] ["credentials"];
            $appConfigurations ["connectionString"] = ('mysql:host=' . $credentials ["hostname"] . ';port=' . $credentials ["port"] . ';dbname=' . $credentials ["schema"] . ';');
        } else {
            $credentials = $dbDetailsObject ['p-mysql'] [0] ["credentials"];
            $appConfigurations ["connectionString"] = ('mysql:host=' . $credentials ["hostname"] . ';port=' . $credentials ["port"] . ';dbname=' . $credentials ["name"] . ';');
        }

        $appConfigurations ["userName"] = $credentials ["username"];
        $appConfigurations ["password"] = $credentials ["password"];

        if (array_key_exists ( "appGuid", $credentials ) && $credentials ["appGuid"] != NULL) {
            $cf_instance_ip = getenv ( "CF_INSTANCE_IP" );
            $appConfigurations ["password"] = self::decrypt_password ( $credentials ["password"], $cf_instance_ip, $credentials ["appGuid"] );
        }

        return $appConfigurations;
    }
}
```

Comment: "App not allowed to create tables in MySQL" "The application mostly works as expected except MySQL database does not allows the application to create tables." How did you know that did you get some kind of error message? If so post the error message here.

Comment: VCAP_SERVICES is how your application can access information provided by the platform.  With CF, you create a service instance and bind it to your application.  The act of doing this tells the platform that you want the app to be able to use that service.  The platform makes this happen by exposing that service instance's information through VCAP_SERVICES.  It's up to your application to read VCAP_SERVICES and utilize the information there.  It looks like the script that you were provided is doing that.  It's also reading some environment variables too, and using those for config.

Comment: See this link for more on service binding -> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/index.html#application-binding

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a matter of giving the db user the proper rights?